# Python Calendar list of arrays

Tags: python, pandas, numpy

I am looking for a functionality in python that can help accomplish the below. I have looked at different packages hoping that this functionality would exist but to no avail.

I have

- start and ending date
- list of holidays between the two
- workdays (Saturday =Yes or No, Sunday = Yes or No)

I need to generate the following

- List of dates dates = ['4/1/2017','4/2/2017'.....end]
- boolean array working/non-working =['1','1,'0','0',...end]
- List of Month WK numbers within month = [ 'APR W1','APR W2',..end]

If one doesnt exist, i need to create a separate routine.

Thanks

Comment: Sounds like you need to get coding then!

Comment: Try holidays: https://pypi.python.org/pypi/holidays. It might help you solve your problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you can use a dictionary to define workdays/non-workdays.
Here's an example:

```
calendar = {

    "jan1": 1,
    "jan2": 1,
    "jan3": 1,
    "jan4": 1,
    "jan5": 1,
    "jan6": 0

    }
```

And call one like this:

```
print calendar["jan3"]
```

Alternatively, you can do this:

```
jan1 = {"day": "Mon"}
jan2 = {"day": "Tue"}
jan3 = {"day": "Wed"}
jan4 = {"day": "Thu"}
jan5 = {"day": "Fri"}
jan6 = {"day": "Sat"}

if jan3["day"] != "Sat" or jan3["day"] != "Sun":
    echo "Work Day"
```